# cakePHP bake fails on opening .core.php file

Tags: php, cakephp

im trying to bake a test project to evaluate cakePHP 2.4.1, and when i do cake bake, before the DB configuration i get the following warnings\errors:

```
Warning Error: file_get_content(/core.pp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [C:\cakePHP\lib\cake\Utility\File.php, line 157]
```

and after that, a whole bunch of errors (unable to set seed, unable to set cache prefix , unable to set CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH etc.)

Any help will be appreciated, 
Boris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
i set the skel path to the cakePHP base folder, and not to cakePHP\app.

Answer (score 0):

I also setup recently cakePHP 2.4.1 and there is no error as such you described. Also there is no file like core.pp, it is core.php.

You can download it again from https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/zipball/2.4.1 and set it up again.